# Mask URL of 301 redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I'm wondering how you do this with .htaccess. I have a URL that is `www.websites.com/seo_packages.htm` and I'd like `www.websites.com/seo-packages` to be what they type to get to the previous URL. I've done it as a 301 redirect, however it doesn't retain the masking of `/seo-packages`. What's the best way to retain the masking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a single rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(seo-packages)/?$ $1.htm [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "retain the masking", but you could create a file `www.websites.com/seo-packages/index.html` with the following content:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=www.websites.com/seo_packages.htm">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will automatically redirect visitors to the new URL.

Comment: This is the problem, i'm trying to keep away from having to create a directory but it's probably going to be the only way

Comment: Masking meaning /seo-packages/ showing in the URL instead of seo_packages.htm